# Optimal volume setup in Glusterfs

Tags: storage, glusterfs

I have a number of servers and am wondering what the most optimal volume setup would be. Initially, there'll be 5 servers but over 20 later on. Each server has 16 x 3TB drives.

Essentially, I want to provide one, large volume with a good level of redundancy and reasonable write speeds. What sort of volume setup would be good to try? Is there any benefit in presenting the drives as 8 x software raid striped pairs, etc. or is it best to stick to 16 bricks?